# Error yarn / ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: react-native, yarn

No ambiente windows, ao usar o yarn para instalar dependência em um projeto react native, surge erro:
**ENOENT: no such file or directory, open...**

Para resolver, apago node_modules e yarn.lock, em seguida executo "yarn install" e, por último, instalo a dependência. Isso resolve, mas ao instalar uma outra dependência, o mesmo erro ocorre e preciso refazer todo o processo.

Qual seria o motivo? 
Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,
Eu no seu caso reinstalaria o nodeJs, se continuasse a dar erro tentaria usar o npm.